# How to prevent random referrals to my website in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-spam

When I look at my Google Analytics dashboard, I see most referrals from a website called rank-checker.online which highly skews up my data.

There are other such websites, get-rick-quick, free-social buttons etc, because of which I am unable to get an actual overview of the site users. Is there a way to not see the data from these?